# Return value from a third table field based on second table id

Tags: mysql, join

I have this tables

`ADDS` (1)

```
+----+--------------+--------------+
| id | name of add  | Date         |
+----+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | Add01        | March 01     |
|  2 | Add02        | March 02     |
|  3 | Add03        | March 03     |
|  4 | Add04        | March 04     |
+----+--------------+--------------+
```

`TYPE OF ADDS` (2)

```
+----+----------+
| id | Add id   |
+----+----------+
| 21 | 1        |  NOTE: Add id of table (2) = id of table (1)
| 22 | 2        |
| 23 | 3        |
| 24 | 4        |
+----+----------+
```

`NAMES OF TYPES` (3)

```
+----+-----------+--------------+
| id | Type id   | Name         |
+----+-----------+--------------+
| 31 | 21        | Text add     |
| 32 | 22        | Banner       | NOTE: Type id of table (3) = id of table (2)
| 33 | 23        | Video add    |
| 34 | 24        | Other        |
+----+-----------+--------------+
```

I need a report like this:

```
+--------+-----------+--------------+
| Add id | Add name  | Type of add  |
+--------+-----------+--------------+
|  1     | Add01     | Text add     |
|  2     | Add02     | Banner       |
|  3     | Add03     | Video add    |
|  4     | Add04     | Other        |
+--------+-----------+--------------+
```

(`Add id` from table (1), `Add name` from table (1), `Type of add` from table (3))

So far I can do a `SELECT query LEFT JOIN table 1 and 2` but I don't know how to return the value `Name of type` from table 3. How can I do it?

Comment: Just FYI because this makes my eyes bleed when I see it, I think the word you are looking for is "ad" (short for advertisement), not "add".  "Add" is something you do to two numbers to produce a sum.  ;)

Comment: You are right, it's just that I was to focus on the 'query language' that I forgot the English language!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join again with table 3:

```
SELECT t1.`id`          AS `Add id`,
       t1.`name of add` AS `Add name`,
       t3.`Name`        AS `Type of add`
FROM   `ADDS` AS t1
  LEFT JOIN `TYPE OF ADDS`   AS t2 ON t2.`Add id`  = t1.`id`
  LEFT JOIN `NAMES OF TYPES` AS t3 ON t3.`Type id` = t2.`id`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  ad.id, ad.name,t.name
FROM ADDS ad
LEFT JOIN TYPEADDS ta ON ta.add_id = ad.id
LEFT JOIN TYPES t ON t.id = ta.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `table1`.`id` AS `Add id`, `table1`.`name_of_add` AS `Add name`, `table3`.`Name` AS `Type of add`
FROM `table1`, `table2`, `table3`
WHERE `table1`.`id` = `table2`.`add_id` AND `table2`.`id` = `table3`.`Type_id`
```

Comment: Unrelated, could someone link a resource that explains the benefits of JOIN vs FROM multiple tables?

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't see the simplest solution, I was trying to do some kind of sub-query. Thanks for your help! This community rocks, you guys answer in less than a minute while I have being waiting for days in other sites!

Comment: I have always considered this type of query the easiest to understand, but I fear it must have some sort of performance issues considering everyone else uses JOIN.

Comment: I'm using DRUPAL with custom fields and the table structure is auto-generated so I can't do nothing but JOIN the fields. In DRUPAL you get a single table for each 'custom field' you add to your content types. What could be a better approach to this kind of queries?

Comment: I know nothing about DRUPAL, sorry.

Comment: Actually I was not asking about DRUPAL but other approach to do this kind of queries?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
select ADDS.nameofadds,TYPEOFADDS.ADDid,NAMEOFTYPES.Name
    FROM ADDS 
    JOIN TYPEOFADDS 
         ON  ADDS.id=TYPEOFADDS.ADDid
    JOIN NAMEOFTYPES 
         ON  TYPEOFADDS.id=NAMEOFTYPES.TYPEid
```